# reference to query is ambiguous (jdbcTemplate)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I cloned project from git and code is working on another machines.
just for me have errors, look at code and error:

And similar to this error is repeated in other places and other classes. I really have no idea.
I used different JDKs, different version of Gradle settings and tomcat settings correctly. The code runs on other computers, but not on my system.

```
@Override
    public Long findLastPolicy(long policyId) {
        Long firstPolicy = findFirstPolicy(policyId);
        if (firstPolicy == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final List<Long> lastPolicyId = new ArrayList<>();
        jdbcTemplate.query("select id from ( " +
                " select qsn3.fk_plc id from cmn.tbi_questionnaire_tree qsn3 where qsn3.fk_plc_anct = ?  and qsn3.fk_plc is not null" +
                " order by qsn3.endorsement_sequence desc " +
                " ) where rowNum < 2", resultSet -> {
            lastPolicyId.add(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        }, firstPolicy);
        return lastPolicyId.get(0);
    }
```

> error: reference to query is ambiguous
> jdbcTemplate.query("select id from ( " +
> ^
> both method query(String,ResultSetExtractor,Object...) in JdbcTemplate and method query(String,RowCallbackHandler,Object...) in JdbcTemplate match
> where T is a type-variable:
> T extends Object declared in method query(String,ResultSetExtractor,Object...)

And at the same point:

> error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
> jdbcTemplate.query("select id from ( " +
> ^
> (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
> missing return value)
> where T is a type-variable:
> T extends Object declared in method query(String,ResultSetExtractor,Object...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I deleted all jdk's and gradle and ide and all file and folders about  ide and reinstalled all of them again.